# Irregular "write ECONNABORTED Error" with Flask request.authorization

Tags: flask, postman

I'm building python web API through Flask. I'm trying to add authorization mechanism with **flask.request.authorization** method. It works great when correct user information are provided. However, when I was trying to input unauthorized user information, it returns "Error: write ECONNABORTED" **irregularly**. What are the possibles causes of this?

I use Postman and input the authorization info under "Authorization" tab in Postman with type "Basic Auth".

For example, when input "Username" as "eric" and "Password" as "secret" in Postman "Authrization" tab, it works fine. But if input "Username" as "debbie" and "Password" as "secret", it sometimes shows "Error: write ECONNABORTED"

```
    app = Flask(__name__)

    def auth_required(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            auth = request.authorization
            if auth and auth.username == 'eric' and auth.password == 'secret':
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            return 'could not verify'
        return decorated       

    @app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @auth_required
    def upload():      
        foo()
        return render_template('upload.html')
```

"SSL certificate verification" is off, "Request timeout in ms" is set to 1000, "Use the system proxy" is checked

Comment: Findings: when add files in Postman "Body (form-data)" with @auth_required decorator added in the code, the error happens irregularly. Otherwise, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: If the app is deployed on Ngrok, the issue will be solved... Still not clear why it happens when running the app on local